# Oblique Projection in Directx?

Tags: directx

Making a 3d scene in my game(stereographic double projection). I was looking for a Direct X version of a LH or RH Matrix for oblique projection. Does directx have a function or will I have to make my own?

Comment: You question has a question mark, but no actual question.

Comment: It's still not clear what actual problem you're trying to solve here. Tell us what you're trying to do, not how you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 2):

DirectXMath doesn't have a function for computing stereo projection matrices in the standard library.

There is code for creating a stereo projection (right-handed) in the Windows 8.1 Store app [Direct3D stereoscopic 3D](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Direct3D-111-Simple-Stereo-9b2b61aa) sample in the `Stereo3DMatrixHelper.h/.cpp` files.

There is also a prototype of a stereo projection helper with additional controls which you can find on the DirectXMath [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) as [Stereo3DMatrixHelper.h](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath/blob/master/Stereo3D/Stereo3DMatrixHelper.h) / [.cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath/blob/master/Stereo3D/Stereo3DMatrixHelper.cpp)